# Shuffle a dictionary of lists aggregating by rows

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a `defaultfict(list)` that might look like this

`d = {0: [2, 4, 5], 1: [5, 6, 1]}`

that I need to shuffle all the first elements from all of the lists together, and move one to the second and third rows. So in this example I need to take `[2, 5], [4, 6], [5, 1]` shuffle them and then put them back. At the end my dictionary might look like this

`d = {0: [5, 4, 1], 1: [2, 6, 5]}`

is there a pythonic way of doing this avoiding loops?

What I have until now is a way to extract and aggregate all the first, second, etc., elements of the lists and shuffle them using this

`[random.sample([tmp_list[tmp_index] for tmp_list in d.values()], 2) for tmp_index in range(3)]`

that will create the following

`[[2, 5], [4, 6], [5, 1]]`

and then in order to create my final shuffled-by-rows dictionary I use simple `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a transposed version of the dict values:

```
>>> data = [list(v) for v in zip(*d.values())]    
>>> data
[[2, 5], [4, 6], [5, 1]]
```

2. Shuffle them in-place

```
>>> for x in data:
...     random.shuffle(x)
...

>>> data
[[5, 2], [4, 6], [5, 1]]
```

3. Transpose the data again

```
>>> data = zip(*data)
```

4. Assign the new values to the dict

```
>>> for x, k in zip(data, d):
...     d[k][:] = x  # Could also be written as d[k] = list(x)
...

>>> d
{0: [5, 4, 5], 1: [2, 6, 1]}
```